# PHP - Upload múltiplo de arquivos não salva com a extensão .txt

Tags: php, txt, multiple-file-upload

galera.

Estou tentando fazer um upload múltiplo de arquivos que aceite todos os tipos de arquivos e salves com a extensão correta, porém nos arquivos .txt ele salva com a extensão .plain, tentei mudar esta extensão fazendo uma verificação mas foi em vão.

Sou iniciante em PHP, alguém pode me ajudar please?

Segue meu código atual:

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
if(count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) > 0){
    for($q=0;$q<count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);$q++){

        $extension = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($extension, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ($ext == 'Text'){
            $ext = 'txt';
        }

        $filename = md5($_FILES['file']['name'][$q].time().rand(0,9999)).$ext;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$q], 'files/'.$filename);

    }
}
}
?>
```

Havia tentado de outra forma também:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
if(count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) > 0){
    for($q=0; $q<count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $q++){

        $extension = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $extension = explode('.', $extension);
        $extension[1];

        $filename = md5($_FILES['file']['name'][$q].time().rand(0,9999)).'.'.$extension[1];

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$q], 'files/'.$filename);

    }
}
}
```

Se eu faço o mesmo procedimento para upload de arquivo único ele salva corretamente como .txt:

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];

if(isset($file['tmp_name']) && !empty($file['tmp_name'])){

$extension = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$extension = explode('.', $extension);
$extension[1];

$filename = md5(time().rand(0,9999)).'.'.$extension[1];

move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], 'files/'.$filename);
}
```

Alguma dica de o por quê estar dando errado? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: E se o cara colocar "." (ponto) no meio do nome do arquivo!?

Answer (score 0):

Faltou por o índice do arquivo igual você fez no md5:

De:

```php
$extension = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Para:

```php
$extension = $_FILES['file']['name'][$q];
```

Comment: E se o cara colocar "." (ponto) no meio do nome do arquivo!?

Comment: Eu testei o código que você informou como implementação atual, o que não tem `explode` e sim a `pathinfo`. Com `pathinfo` se o cara colocar "nome.do.arquivo.com.ponto.no.meio.txt" vai retornar somente "txt"